# How to ip throught piping?

Tags: pipe, ip, gnome-terminal

I gather all my local ip using `arp-scan` , Then filter particular system ip by mac address, And connect automatically to that particular system using ssh. I tried the following commands through piping

```
 sudo arp-scan --localnet|grep 10|cut -c1-12|xargs ssh myuser@
```

Here 1c in `grep` is the mac address starting letter of  my system.

Its return the following error

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname : Name or service not known
>
> xargs: ssh: exited with status 255; aborting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use *xargs* Replacement String Flag

You need to use the replacement string flag for xargs. For example, assuming the rest of your pipeline works as intended:

```
sudo arp-scan --localnet | grep 10 | cut -c1-12 | xargs -I{} -n1 ssh -tt myuser@{}
```

Note that both the *xargs* and *ssh* commands need some additional flags to work properly. Of special note is the need to pass the `-tt` flags to SSH in order to force PTY allocation on the remote host when the SSH client is receiving standard input from a pipe.

### Use Command Substitution and Shell Variables

Alternatively, if you're accurately capturing a single IP address, you can just capture the result in a shell variable and invoke SSH on the correct host. For example, using the Bash shell:

```
host_ip=$(sudo arp-scan --localnet | grep 10 | cut -c1-12)
ssh "myuser@${host_ip}"
```

The primary advantage of this approach is that it's easier to debug. However, your mileage may vary.

Comment: The first method gives following error  **Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname interface: e: Name or service not known
xargs: ssh: exited with status 255; aborting
**

Comment: @SuperKrish The pseudo-terminal error is because you're taking standard input from a pipe. You may have to force PTY allocation by passing the `-tt` flags to ssh. Other SSH errors will be outside the scope of your original question.

Comment: i add **ssh -tt**  like this, but still i got this Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
error.Instead of connecting it Returns this "welcome message only"

Answer (score 1):

- The first problem is that you are trying to run `ssh myuser@ x.y.z.t` (where x.y.z.t is the IP address identified). Won't work. You need `ssh myuser@x.y.z.t` (note that there is no space netween `myuse@` and the IP address). You may try `sudo arp-scan --localnet | grep ... | sed -e 's/^/myuser@/' | xargs ssh`.
- The second problem is that `ssh` won't establish an interactive session, complaining that standard input is not a terminal. To keep `ssh` happy, you must do the IP address selection in a command substitution:

  ```
  ACCOUNTNAME=myuser
  MACADDRESS=00:50:56:3a:8d:1e
  ssh "$ACCOUNTNAME@$(
    sudo arp-scan --localnet |
    grep "$MACADDRESS" |
    cut -c 1-15
  )"
  ```

I hope that the `grep` shown is just an example and for real you use the full MAC address.

You may want to add some error handling code, in case `grep` fails to find the IP address corresponding to the given MAC address.

Comment: everything is fine, I can able to find ip. The problem the gathered ip not able to pass into **ssh user@ section**

Comment: I have explained that. `xargs` does not concatenate arguments. You need a `sed` between the `grep` and the `xargs` to stick the `myuser@` in front of the IP address.

Comment: i not using **sed** before, sorry to ask please guide to how to use **sed**, Here

Comment: `ACCOUNTNAME=myuser ; MACADDRESS=00:50:56:3a:8d:1e ; sudo arp-scan --localnet | grep "$MACADDRESS" | cut -c 1-15 | sed -e "s/^/$ACCOUNTNAME@/" | xargs ssh` Note that `cut -c 1-15` not `1-12`.

Comment: In have expanded the answer explaining what needs to be done to obtain an interactive session. In short, use `ACCOUNTNAME=myuser ; MACADDRESS=00:50:56:3a:8d:1e ; ssh "$ACCOUNTNAME@$(sudo arp-scan --localnet | grep "$MACADDRESS" | cut -c 1-15)"`.